# Keyboard Shortcut to run command in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm building my Javascript bundle using a pre-build event in Visual Studio 2013 (2015 too).

Is there any way I can bind a hot-key in Visual Studio to run this command from within Visual Studio instead of having to open another console window?

`webpack.cmd --config ..\webpack.config.js`

The reason I want to do this is that I don't want to have to rebuild my entire project every time I change a javascript file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2015 has a new, very sophisticated event system built in and can do that easily. Just install the grunt-contrib-watch package and you can configure any grunt tasks to happen on save.

2013 would require an external app/ plugin and I am not aware of any popular ones. You could likely build your own if you were so inclined, the plugin system on VS is extensive, and if you wanted to go the easy route, a simple tray app with a filesystem watcher would do what you are asking.